# Strongly-ordered memory and imprecise aborts

Tags: linux, arm

As per ARM Cortex-A programming Guide:

> Device probing therefore needs special handling, as externally
>   reported aborts on reads to non-existent areas will generate
>   imprecise, asynchronous aborts even when such memory is marked as
>   Strongly-ordered, or Device.

I fail to understand how a memory marked as SO or Device has anything to do with imprecise aborts. They can also occur if memory is normal.

Right?

Answer (score 2):

The point here is **device probing**. One might think that since device memory is strongly ordered it's OK to map a region, then read from a bunch of addresses in turn to see if there's anything behind them (since you know the CPU isn't going to confuse matters by speculating, caching, reordering, etc.) and you'll either get data back or an abort for each address. However, *external* aborts are beyond the control of the MMU, so the non-presence of a device can result in an *imprecise* abort regardless of the memory attributes - there's no way to know *which* access caused it, thus you don't know which device isn't there.

In other words, "Even if you impose strong ordering on all memory accesses, it won't necessarily apply to external aborts, so take care if you're doing something that might cause one."

As explained in the rest of the paragraph the original quote comes from, the only reasonable way to *generally* handle imprecise aborts is to kill whatever generated them - if you don't know *what* went wrong, you can't recover from it - so obviously if that abort comes from your kernel probing devices and it kills itself, that's not good. Hence the need for "special" handling in that case.

Comment: I think my question is a bit different. Its not about special handling but about, how "even when such memory is marked as Strongly-ordered, or Device" fits here. If there is no external device or memory present  there would always be an abort.

Comment: @mSO Indeed, there would always be an abort - what matters is the _type_ of abort. Specifically, that it isn't constrained by the ordering attributes and may be asynchronous regardless.